# ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'hub_root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried to create a MySQL User, and always I get this error:

> ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for
>   'hub_root'@'localhost'

These are the steps I tried:

```
root@host:/var/www/html# mysql -u root -h localhost
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 104
Server version: 10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'hub_root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Swasdadrwtfwt4567';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'hub_root'@'localhost'
```

After this I take a look into the user table, but there is no user like this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
Database changed
MariaDB [mysql]> select user,host, plugin from user;
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User   | Host      | plugin                |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root   | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| mysql  | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| dbroot | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+

MariaDB [mysql]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> CREATE USER 'hub_root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Swasdadrwtfwt4567';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'hub_root'@'localhost'
MariaDB [mysql]>
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have the `mysql_native_password` or `mysql_old_password` plugins, so you can't use an unhashed password there.

Comment: See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#identified-by-password

Comment: Ok never run in this error before. I have Ubuntu 18.10 with MariaDB 10.4.12-MariaDB. How can I check if the plugins exists? I login the root user without password too

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, this is about administering a mysql server. Therefore this question is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO offers help for such questions.